# How to automate a image in canvas from selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, canvas

In my project, I need to click on an image drawn in the canvas. I am able to do it with coordinates. But that is not the right way to do, because each time different images with different size, gets loaded. So sometimes there will be empty space around the image on canvas depending on the height and width of that image. And this image cannot be located through DOM. Is there any way for Selenium to find the boundaries of these images which gets loaded(dynamic)? So that I can mouse click within the image.

```
xord = Integer.parseInt(ExcelUtils.getnumData(i, 5));
          yord = Integer.parseInt(ExcelUtils.getnumData(i, 6));
          new Actions(driver).moveToElement(target, xord, yord).click().perform();
```

**More details on project:**
This page has a canvas on which image gets loaded. 
Test scenario is to select a dropdown, which will load the image on this canvas.
In positive test case, mouse click anywhere inside the image.
In negative test case, mouse click anywhere outside the image within canvas space.

Comment: depends on your dom. My guess js executor in selenium would do the thing for you.

Comment: Can you give some more details ?? like some code or application in which you are trying to automate

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: @DebanjanB here is my code trial:   xord = Integer.parseInt(ExcelUtils.getnumData(i, 5));
    yord = Integer.parseInt(ExcelUtils.getnumData(i, 6));
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(target, xord, yord).click().perform();